# timeout external spring service in asp.net project

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spring, web-services

I have an ASP.NET project. In this project, I make many external service calls. For example a spring service. When I call this spring service, I expect an answer to ASP.NET within 1 minute. ASP.NET throws exception when timeout. In this case, can the external service java side (spring) continue? If it continues, should I block it on the java side or on the ASP.NET side? I do not want the external service (Java spring service) to continue.